# Python doesn't delete temporary file if the program fails

Tags: python, temporary-files

I'm writing a program, which, inter alia, works with temporary file, created using `tempfile` library.

The temporary file creates and fills in function:

```
def func():
    mod_script = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir='special')
    dest = open(mod_script, 'w')
    #  filling dest
    return mod_script
```

(I use `open()` and not `with open()` because I execute the temporary file after calling `func()`)

After some operations with `mod_script` outside `func()`, I call `mod_script.close()`. And all works fine.

**But I have one problem.** If my program fails (or if I interrupt it), the temporary file doesn't remove.

How do I fix it ?

I really don't want to write `try...except...finally` clauses because I'll have to write it so many times (there are many points, where my program can fail).

Comment: Why do you assume you'd have to write try/except/finally everywhere if the goal is just to delete the file and then re-raise the exception? Why can't you just let the exception bubble up and wrap the outmost level of your code with the try? Or even better, write a context manager that removes the file on exit.

Comment: "I use open() and not with open() because I execute the temporary file after calling func()" - huh? I don't understand your reasoning. elaborate.

Comment: After returning `mod_script` I use it in many places. And my program can fail before first using of `mod_script` or between `n`st and `n + 1`st... If I add `try...except` if `func()` it'll not save the situation.

Comment: If you use "try ... open file ... call function that does all the processing and may fail  ... [except] ... finally ... delete the file", you will not have to write it "everywhere", but only in one place.

Answer (score 1):

First, use a `with` statement, and [pass `delete=False` to the constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html?highlight=namedtemporary#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile).

Then you need to put the necessary error handling in your program.  Catch exceptions (see [try..finally](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions)) and clean up during program exit whether it is successful or crashes.

Alternatively, keep the file open while executing it to prevent the automatic deletion-on-close from deleting it before you have executed it.  This may have issues on Windows where it tends to have conflicts using files that are open.